# Having trouble multiplying two matrices

Tags: java, loops, matrix, product

Sorry,this is a homework problem. I am not good with maths, so I checked out some videos to understand how two matrices are multiplied. I came up with a formula, but I do not know what I am doing wrong? This question has been answered before, but I did not understand. Thank you.

```
    case 3:
          System.out.println("THE PRODUCT OF TWO MATRICES ARE: "); 

     for(i =0; i< arrayList.length; i++){
           for(j =0; j< arrayList1.length; j++){
             for(k =0; k < arrayList1.length;k++){
               multiplication = arrayList[i][k] * arrayList1[k][j] +  multiplication;

          }
          System.out.print(arrayList[i][j]+" ");    

        }

   System.out.println();
      }

    break;
```

Comment: @hexafraction What makes you think they are lists? It's just arrays named `arrayList`. (even though the names are misleading, I agree).

Comment: @ZouZou How would I know that they are arrays not lists if I cannot see their declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should understand that the multiplication of two matrices should result in a matrice (which not appear to be the case with your `multiplication` variable).

I suppose you have to program the basic implementation. Let's take a look at the following matrices.

[image]

`A` has `n` rows, and `m` columns; said to be a matrice `n x m`.
Similary, `B` has `m` rows and `p` columns (`m x p` matrice). The multiplication of `A x B` will give you a matrice `n x p`.

[image]

Note that if you want to do the multiplication `A x B`, the matrice `A` must have the same number of columns that the number of rows of the matrice `B`.

Now each value in the matrice `AB` (i<sup>th</sup> row and j<sup>th</sup> column) is computed as follow:

[image]

That said, let's take a look at the Java implementation (which is a pure translation of the mathematical formula).

```
public static int[][] multiply(int[][] matrixA, int[][] matrixB) {
    int[][] result = new int[matrixA.length][matrixB[0].length];

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < result[0].length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < matrixB.length; k++) {
                result[i][j] += matrixA[i][k] * matrixB[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The `result` matrice is initialized at the right dimensions. Then the first two nested loop (with indices `i` and `j`) will loop through all the elements of elements of the resulting matrice. Then you just need the third loop to compute the sum.

You'd still need to check that the matrices you give as parameters have the correct length.

The algorithm used is pretty naive (O(n<sup>3</sup>) complexity). If you don't understand it, there's a lot of resources in the web that explains how it works; but that would more a mathematical question than a programming one.

Hope it helps ! :)